# Is an HttpModule security based sufficient to guarantee the security of an asp.net application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, httpmodule

Working on an `ASP.NET` Application I have implemented a page level access control using a custom `HttpModule` this `HttpModule` intercept each incoming request and check if the connected user can access the requested page if not it redirect him to an Error page.

- Is this approach sufficient to guarantee the security of the application or is it easy to bypass it,
- and what do you recommend to improve it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what type of authentication are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as there is nothing in the standard libraries which could be used for what you want, this should be fine, provided you've adequately tested your module.  You can't bypass a HttpModule without getting access to the server itself to modify the web.config file, and if an attacker has already done that, then this is the least of your worries!

If there IS something in the standard libraries that could be used, you should prefer this, since it will inevitably have been tested extensively by others!

I'd recommend getting a decent set of unit tests written for your module, since it will form the main line of defence for your application!

Answer (score 1):

> Is this approach sufficient to guarantee the security of the application or is it easy to bypass it,

It is good enough to secure that every user is authorized to call the URL.

It does NOTHING to secure you from the usual attacks that form the basis of SQL Injection - bad parameter validation and text to SQL atocieties.

Comment: for the moment i differ those wories to another step. now i m focusing only on resticting the users from accessing pages i don't allow to them